# api json response not coming in array form

Tags: php, laravel, rest

First of all I am new to laravel.

This is my controller

```
$itemsList=Items::all()->where('shop_id',$request->shop_id);

return response()->json(['data'=>$itemsList]);
```

This is the response

```
{
    "data": {
        "10": {
            "id": 11,
            "shop_id": 1,
            "title": "Test",
            "price_nd": 12,
            "price_wd": 10,
            "updated_at": "2019-11-14 00:00:00",
            "created_at": "2019-11-14 00:00:00"
        },
        "11": {
            "id": 12,
            "shop_id": 1,
            "title": "Test",
            "price_nd": 12,
            "price_wd": 10,
            "updated_at": "2019-11-14 00:00:00",
            "created_at": "2019-11-14 00:00:00"
        },
        "14": {
            "id": 15,
            "shop_id": 1,
            "title": "Test",
            "price_nd": 12,
            "price_wd": 10,
            "updated_at": "2019-11-14 00:00:00",
            "created_at": "2019-11-14 00:00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem is I want to return an array list of the items**

I tried many approached but I don't know what is the problem or what I am missing

Comment: just do dd($itemsList); and see whats coming..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try.** Use get() method .

*`get()` and `all()` both get same output but*

*`all()` method not useful for use where condition.
`get()` method can useful to use other conditions*

```
$itemsList=Items::where('shop_id',$request->shop_id)->get();

return response()->json(['data'=>$itemsList]);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Try this code..

```
  $itemsList=Items::where('shop_id',$request->shop_id)->get();
  dd($itemsList); // add this step in your code
  return response(['data' => $itemsList]);
```

Comment: dd()  functions is used for debugging purpose in Laravel(php). if you gets stuck while fetching the data from the db use this function.

Answer (score 1):

You this approach.

```
return response(['data' => $itemsList]);
```

Comment: still no change